# WPF Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I have recently started getting the exception "`Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first."` after converting a bunch of `Frame` controls to simpler `ContentControl` controls to host sub-model views within their logical parent model views.

In the below example, the commented out code when commented out will stop the crash from occurring:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GUI.Views.Scenario.PathogenRiskLiquidIngestionView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:ScenModels="clr-namespace:GUI.ViewModels.ScenarioModels">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <DockPanel>
                <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Risk Assessment Title"></Label>
                <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding RiskAssessmentTitle, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel>
                <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Risk Calculated"></Label>
                <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding RiskCalculated, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding RiskCalculatedOptions}"></ComboBox>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel>
                <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="{Binding MinAcceptableInfectionRiskLabel}"></Label>
                <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding MinAcceptableInfectionRisk, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <!--<GroupBox Header="Pathogens">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Button Content="Add Pathogen" Command="{Binding AddPathogen}"></Button>
                    <Button Content="Remove Pathogen" Command="{Binding RemovePathogen}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=PathogenList}"></Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <ListView Name="PathogenList" ItemsSource="{Binding PathogensPresentViews}" Tag="{Binding}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ScenModels:PathogenPresentIngestViewModel}">
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"></ContentControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Header="Receptor Characteristics">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding ReceptorVolumeLiquidIngestedPerEventView}"></ContentControl>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding ExposuresView}"></ContentControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>-->
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

After doing a search for this kind of exception the most common cause seems to be some incorrect styling, however in this application I have not yet styled any elements. Can someone please tell me what is likely to be causing this exception?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that this seems to be the only view causing this error and there is very similar XAML in other views that does not cause this error.

Comment: Seriously, the error is so simple to understand, it does not matter if a common cause is styling, you can easily deduce what can cause this and have a look at relevant code parts.

Comment: The exception happens when an element already is added as a child somewhere, hence the critical places are: Where UI-elements are referenced & where UI-elements are programatically added and removed from the tree. Stuff like `{Binding ExposuresView}` just cries tree-confict, you shouldn't even be having references to views in your data. I can't tell you where exactly the problem is though (you should be the one tracking it down).

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think its as simple as your stating, I cannot see anyway for one of these views to end up as the logical child of multiple elements and that is why I am having trouble tracking this down.

Comment: Well, you somehow manage to do that nonetheless and you would not be in this mess if you had a proper model-view separation in place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more knowledge of what all the underlying objects are i can not do much more than guessing...

Here is something *really* fishy:

```
<ListView Name="PathogenList" ItemsSource="{Binding PathogensPresentViews}" Tag="{Binding}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ScenModels:PathogenPresentIngestViewModel}">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"></ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

As mentioned in the comments you should never even have a situation where you bind to `*Views`, the view model should not have references to views, but only view models. There is little point in following a model-view-separation pattern if you violate it like that.

Anyway, as you bind to what presumably are views and hence UI-elements something undesirable might be happening here:

1. `DataTemplate` is created: View is added to `ContentControl` -> Now a child of a control
2. `ListView` goes *"Well screw the `DataTemplate`, i can display this item as is."* (Because it is a view, which it *should not be*).
3. `ListView` adds item (the view, which is the child of the `ContentControl`) to the `ItemsPanel`.
4. Whoops!

But that is probably not it, WPF should be smarter than that, so how about this: Multiple references to the same instance in the `PathogensPresentViews` list?

Or the same view model is used in two places, creating two views, which both try to display the same list of UI-elements?

Whatever the actual case may be, you should not fight the symptoms but the illness, which most likely is that your view models contain views.

Comment: I get what your saying about the views, but this is a really myterious issue as it works fine in some cases but under very specific circumstances throws this exception, but leaves no clue as to why. I will try refactoring my view structure to bind data contexts rather then whole views.

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor: Many UI-oparations are asynchronous, so there might be some undefined behaviour stemming from that. Out of curiosity, do you use any MVVM framework?

Comment: Yeah I have a domain model, which I built a bunch of view models on top of, then I made a bunch of views for the view models with all the program logic in the view models. The reason my view models have the views in them is because of a library system I wrote in which requires the views to take a model parameter in their constructor, but I could just add a second parameterless constructor to each view to allow for them to be created in XAML by other views.

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor: I meant if you use something like Prism or Caliburn. Anyway, you should not need to pass a reference to the view, that happens automatically when the view is placed where it is needed and it gets the VM as DataContext. The whole view creation business is nasty, i myself completely delegate that to WPF by using *implicit* `DataTemplates`.

Comment: But in some cases the views need to be created based on a file from disk, this means that I cannot actually write XAML to bind the data context in these cases and the easiest way was to do it through the constructor.

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor: Are you sure this cannot be deferred? The view is not bound to display anything meaningful right away, why not inject the disc file via the VM?

Comment: I think I am injecting the file into the VM? basically I have a VM that takes a file path, figures out what kind of model the file represents and initializes a new VM which loads its data from the file. Then I have a property that binds to a ContentControl on the view and I set the value to a new instance of the determined view using the initialized VM as a parameter.

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor: I thought you meant that you created the view via a constructor that takes the VM as parameter, which i would avoid. If you have constructed the correct VM from the file you should just need to assign that VM to a `ContentPresenter` (i'd recommend that over a `ContentControl`, it's "lighter") and if you have implicit `DataTemplates` in place WPF will construct the right view based on the VM's type. (I wrote a mini MVVM framework which creates the `DataTemplates` automatically, unfortunately it is not published anywhere yet, works quite nicely)

Comment: Can you give me a better understanding of what you mean by DataTemplate's? As it sounds like the kind of thing that would suit my application well.

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor: It's fairly simple for every VM you add `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VMType}"><v:VType /></DataTemplate>` to the `Application.Resources`, whenever that VM is encountered anywhere (without a local template) the respective view is created via this implicit template.

Comment: What would be some example XAML for this data templating technique?

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor: What do you have in mind, did i not just give an example?

Comment: Like how do you go about the automatic datacontext resolving? Or did you just mean add XAML tags for your views and bind the DataContext?

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor: DataContext resolving is a non-issue (i am not even sure what that is supposed to mean). The system is pretty simple, if WPF encounteres an object as content it looks for a DataTemplate for that type. That `DataTemplate` contains the respective view, the view gets the `ViewModel` as `DataContext` because that is being templated.